# javascript window.open without scrollbars?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I'm using javascript window.open for facebook Login.

I have fixed the width and height of the new window.

Now my problem is the new window (facebook) page is very big than my actual window size, so the scroll bars are appearing.

Now my Need is I have to reduce the page size which is showing inside the new Window without affecting window size.

Can anyone Help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is only the css change but I need the whole page which is inside the window size needs to be change.

Comment: Don't change whole page just chaange size of body that will be ok if your are not using `position:absolute` to content

Comment: But I want to load facebook api. so how can I change body of their page. The url is https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xyxyxy&redirect_uri=yyy&state=xxx